# Nested loop execution

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, printing

This is a really simple question, but for some reason I'm getting confused and it's annoying.

```
def test():
for i from Lo1 to Hi1:
    for j from Lo2 to Hi2:
    body()
```

How many times will body() execute for:
Lo1=1, Hi1=n, Lo2=i-2, Hi2=i+2

The answer is 5n times, but I have no idea how they get it!

Comment: How many times do you think it will execute? To begin with, how many times does the loop over j execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to understand is to run it.

For example for `n=10`, the following java code prints values of `i` and `j` in each iteration :

```
 for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
     for (int j=i-2; j<=i+2; j++)
         System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j= " + j);
 }
```

The result is as follows:

```
i = 0, j= -2
i = 0, j= -1
i = 0, j= 0
i = 0, j= 1
i = 0, j= 2
i = 1, j= -1
i = 1, j= 0
i = 1, j= 1
i = 1, j= 2
i = 1, j= 3
i = 2, j= 0
i = 2, j= 1
i = 2, j= 2
i = 2, j= 3
i = 2, j= 4
i = 3, j= 1
i = 3, j= 2
i = 3, j= 3
i = 3, j= 4
i = 3, j= 5
i = 4, j= 2
i = 4, j= 3
i = 4, j= 4
i = 4, j= 5
i = 4, j= 6
i = 5, j= 3
i = 5, j= 4
i = 5, j= 5
i = 5, j= 6
i = 5, j= 7
i = 6, j= 4
i = 6, j= 5
i = 6, j= 6
i = 6, j= 7
i = 6, j= 8
i = 7, j= 5
i = 7, j= 6
i = 7, j= 7
i = 7, j= 8
i = 7, j= 9
i = 8, j= 6
i = 8, j= 7
i = 8, j= 8
i = 8, j= 9
i = 8, j= 10
i = 9, j= 7
i = 9, j= 8
i = 9, j= 9
i = 9, j= 10
i = 9, j= 11
i = 10, j= 8
i = 10, j= 9
i = 10, j= 10
i = 10, j= 11
i = 10, j= 12
```

You can see now that there are `10` iterations for `i`, and for each `i` you have `5` iterations of `j(from i-2 to i+2)`. Hence `50 (5*N)` iterations in total.

Comment: This is awesome, and you're right. It's really easy once you implement the algorithm. I now see what is going on. I'd upvote your answer, but I can't =(

Answer (score 3):

**Lo2=i-2, Hi2=i+2** Inner Loop

> So (i-2)to(i+2)=5 Alternations   `EG:  i-2  ,  i-1  ,  i  ,  i+1  ,  i+2`
>
> *Like (-2) to (+2)=-2,-1,0,1,2*

**Lo1=1, Hi1=n**   Outer Loop

> 1 to N

**So Total** `Inner* Outer`

> 5*N=5N

Comment: SO SIMPLE! I really like that alteration step, it really makes things clear. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'd mark it with the correct answer / upvote it, but I don't have enough rep :(

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is  a for loop with Java code

```
for(int i=3;i<=6;i++)
{
    //Statements to be executed
}
```

The loop will execute 4 times (i=3,4,5,6)

How to calculate?

formula=upper bound-lower bound+1

so in the above loop it will be 6-3+1=4(upper bound=6,lower bound=3)

In your question
upper bound=i+2

lower bound=i-2

total number of times inner loop execute=i+2-(i-2)+1=i+2-i+2+1=5

the outer loop will execute n times so just multiply with n

hence answer becomes 5*n=5n

Comment: Wow, another really good way of looking at it. That formula is very obvious once you explained it to me. Thank you

Comment: I couldn't until just then, @aa1992 I didn't have enough respect.